# C# Window Application?

Tags: c#-4.0

in this code the error is `unclosed quotation marks after the character string '4/21/2014 4:24:05 PM)';` how to resolve this error

```
SqlCommand myCommand = default(SqlCommand);
myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert Into Company_Master(C_Name,M_Name,L_No,PO_No,Location,State,Country,Telephone,Fax_No,Email_Id,WebSite,Currency_Name,Company_logo,Accounting_Period_To,Accounting_Period_From) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" +textBox10.Text+"','"+ textBox11.Text+"','"+textBox12.Text+"','"+textBox13.Text+"','"+ pictureBox1.Image+"','" + dateTimePicker1.Value+"','"+dateTimePicker2.Value+")", myConnection);
```

Comment: use `String.Format` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Make sure you must use SqlParameter to execute queries, don't do formatting of sql query which might attack by Sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Change `dateTimePicker2.Value+")"` to `dateTimePicker2.Value+"')"` with a single quote before the bracket.

Your error is because you aren't terminating the date/time correctly. However, there is a bigger issue with your code. Because you are building the query by concatenating text, you are open to SQL Injection. Instead you should use parameterised queries.